# GLSL 2.0 Shader giving different light in different device

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader

I am trying to write a shader for a opengles 2.0 view in Android.
My shader is :

Vertex shader:

```
 uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;      // A constant representing the combined model/view/projection matrix.
uniform mat4 u_MVMatrix;        // A constant representing the combined model/view matrix.              

attribute vec4 a_Position;      // Per-vertex position information we will pass in.                             
attribute vec3 a_Normal;        // Per-vertex normal information we will pass in.      
attribute vec2 a_TexCoordinate; // Per-vertex texture coordinate information we will pass in.       

varying vec3 v_Position;        // This will be passed into the fragment shader.                            
varying vec3 v_Normal;          // This will be passed into the fragment shader.  
varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;   // This will be passed into the fragment shader.            

// The entry point for our vertex shader.  
void main()                                                     
{                                                         
    // Transform the vertex into eye space.     
    v_Position = vec3(u_MVMatrix * a_Position);

    // Pass through the texture coordinate.
    v_TexCoordinate = a_TexCoordinate;                                      

    // Transform the normal's orientation into eye space.
    v_Normal = normalize(vec3(u_MVMatrix * vec4(a_Normal, 0.0)));

    // gl_Position is a special variable used to store the final position.
    // Multiply the vertex by the matrix to get the final point in normalized screen coordinates.
    gl_Position = (u_MVPMatrix * a_Position);
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
precision highp float;          // Set the default precision to medium. We don't need as high of a 
                                // precision in the fragment shader.
uniform vec3 u_LightPos1;           // The position of the light in eye space.
uniform vec3 u_LightDir1;           // The position of the light in eye space.
float l_spotCutOff=45.0;
uniform sampler2D u_Texture;    // The input texture.

varying vec3 v_Position;        // Interpolated position for this fragment.
varying vec3 v_Normal;          // Interpolated normal for this fragment.
varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;   // Interpolated texture coordinate per fragment.
float cutoff = 0.1;
// The entry point for our fragment shader.
void main()                         
{                              

    // Get a lighting direction vector from the light to the vertex.
    vec3 lightVector1 = normalize(u_LightPos1 - v_Position);

        // Will be used for attenuation.
        float distance1 = length(u_LightPos1 - v_Position);

    float diffuse=0.0;

        // Calculate the dot product of the light vector and vertex normal. If the normal and light vector are
        // pointing in the same direction then it will get max illumination.
    float diffuse1 = max(dot(v_Normal, lightVector1), 0.1);
        // Add attenuation. 
    diffuse1 = diffuse1 * (1.0 / (1.0+(0.25*distance1)));

    // Add ambient lighting
    diffuse = diffuse1+0.2;
    // Multiply the color by the diffuse illumination level and texture value to get final output color.
    vec4 color = (texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate));
    color.rgb *= (diffuse);
    if( color.a < cutoff)
        discard;

    gl_FragColor = color;


  }
```

Now the shaders are working perfectly but its behaving differently in different device:

Device 1: (moto x play)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rb0eU.png)

Device 2: (Samsung S7)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JooYV.png)

Can anyone help?

Comment: `highp float` is not available on all devices, it may be a source of diff.

Comment: I have used mediump   in place of highp , it changed the light intencity but still same effect

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be there in texture format/type which you have used. All devices doesn't support all texture formats. 
for eg : if your output color can have negative values and the texture format of device doesn't support them, it will get clamped to 0 and might give different results.
Better to check capabilities of both devices using

```
   GLES20.glGetString(GLES20.GL_EXTENSIONS));
```